# Does tablets that run on windows 7 have an imei or a unique identifier?

Tags: windows, tablet

Hello and I apologize for my bad english.
I have to do an application for  tablets that run under windows 7.Every employee the firm has has an own tablet.So what I need is an imei or a a unique identifier of the tablet to associate every employee with his tablet.And if it has how can i find it.Thank you very much.I am working in C#

Answer (score 0):

A (wireless, probably on a tablet) network card MAC address is usually regarded as sufficiently unique.